# How do I make a octahedron in Blender 2.8=

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on

I have been searching a lot on how to make an octahedron, but everything doesn't seem to work in the newest update, so I'm just asking if there's been some new way added to make them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can just bevel the default cube.

1. Select all vertices
2. Bevel the cube (check *Clamp overlap*)
3. Remove double vertices *Mesh > Clean up > Merge by Distance*

[image]

Comment: When ur doing bevel just Press C (activate clamp) and just drag ur cursor out

Comment: Sure, the menu is just easier to see in a gif :).

Answer (score 6):

easiest way is with this addon "Add Mesh Extra Objects".

Once activated in "Blender preferences" > "Add-ons" you can do: "Add mesh" > "math functions" > "regular solid".

Once the object is created, open the configuration (loert left part of the screen) and choose "octahedron" as "source"

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. default cube
2. subdivide one edge loop vertically
3. merge top and bottom vertices with "auto merge" turned on
4. select all vertices and apply "to sphere"

[image]